# Entity Framework 4.1 - Select

Tags: entity-framework-4, lambda

I am using the following expressions:

```
ProductRepository.Query.Include(Function(x) x.ChildProducts.Select(Function(y) y.PriceTiers.Where(Function(z) z.IsActive))).Where(Function(x) x.Categories.Any(Function(y) y.ID = ID))
```

And getting this error:

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
```

If I remove this:

```
.Where(Function(z) z.IsActive)
```

It works fine, but I need to filter the inactive price tiers.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here is my solution:

```
Public Function GetProductsByCategoryID(ID As Integer) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Core.Entities.Product) Implements Core.Interfaces.IProductService.GetProductsByCategoryID
        Dim Col = ProductRepository.Query.Where(Function(x) x.Display AndAlso x.Categories.Any(Function(y) y.ID = ID)) _
                  .Select(Function(x) New With { _
                              .Product = x,
                              .ChildProducts = x.ChildProducts.Where(Function(y) y.Display).Select(Function(y) New With { _
                                                                                                       .ChildProduct = y,
                                                                                                       .PriceTiers = y.PriceTiers.Where(Function(z) z.IsActive)
                                                                                                   })
                          }).ToList.Select(Function(x) x.Product)

        Return Col

    End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in single query without projection or separate query to load the navigation property. Lambda expression for `Include` accepts only dotted notation for references and `Select` for collections but you can't do any filtering.

Filtering is possible on in separate query when using DbContext API:

```
var data = context.Entry(product)
                  .Collection(p => p.ChildProducts)
                  .Query()
                  // Here are your filters
                  .Load();
```

Edit:

Projection requires something like:

```
var data = context.Products
                  .Where(...)
                  .Select(p => new 
                      {
                          Product = p,
                          ChildProducts = p.ChildProducts.Where(...)
                      });
```

Comment: @Lad - So this assumes you have a single product to act on correct? If so, how would you do this with a collection of products?

Comment: It doesn't work for collection. You must use custom query with projection instead.

Comment: @Lad - Could you point me to an example of a custom query with projection?

Comment: I added example of projection.

Comment: @Lad - Thanks for the example, but I am just not getting this at all. Do you have to create some sort of DTO object that returns the results you want? I want a collection of `Product` where `Display=True` and `Categories.Any(Function(x) x.ID = IDPassedIn`. I then want the collection of `ChildProdcut` where `Display=True` for each product, and lastly, I want the collection of `PriceTier` for the `ChildProduct` where `IsActive=True`. So it is a three level operation, filtering on each level. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you must create DTO because projection is not possible to mapped entity and in the same type you can't filter eager loaded childs.

Comment: @Lad - Please see my update above. It seems to work pretty well.