# Error when trying to use context.entity.include()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to filter records and return them to put them in a list.  My variable "companyId" equals 1.  When I run, I get an error.  What can I do to fix?  Thank you.

The error points to this line:

```
Dim blogs = db.Blogs.Include(Function(b) b.CompanyId = companyId)
```

The error:

The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path

The whole code:

```
    '
    ' GET: /ViewBlogs/

    Function ViewBlogs() As ViewResult
        'Dim blogs = db.Blogs.Include(Function(b) b.Company)

        Dim db1 As UserProfileDbContext = New UserProfileDbContext
        Dim user = Membership.GetUser()
        Dim key As Guid = user.ProviderUserKey
        Dim userProfile = db1.UserProfiles.Where(Function(p) p.UserId = key).Single
        Dim companyId = userProfile.CompanyId

        If (userProfile.IsCompanyOwner) Then

            Dim blogs = db.Blogs.Include(Function(b) b.CompanyId = companyId)

            Return View(blogs.ToList())

        Else

            Return View("Home")

        End If


    End Function
```

Comment: Visit this answer, it may help you -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658219/entity-framework-4-1-select

Comment: Thank you I have seen that post before I submitted this question.  I am uncertain how to apply it in this context.  Please help.

Comment: Update:  I have changed from using Include to using Where.  It seems to have worked.  I will post back with an answer momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution for me was as simple as this:

```
Dim blogs = db.Blogs.Where(Function(b) b.CompanyId = companyId)
```